# Need help converting a math formula in Python code

Tags: python, math

i have this formula over here:

[image]

I've been working on this for the last 6 hours and can't get a coded version down in Python.
Could someone with some math skills help me out in this task?

Thank you very much,

Edit:
This is my current attempt:

```
def create_group(i, k):
    return (my_list[i] - my_list[i - k]) * my_other_list[i - k]

def computation():
        
    main = []
    new_group_container = []

    for i in range(len(my_list)):
        for k in range(len(main)):
            new_group = create_group(i=i, k=k)
            new_group_container.append(new_group)
        group = sum(new_group_container) 
        main.append(group)

    return main
```

Comment: edited now the code. Thanks

Comment: Could you add some examples of inputs to your program, the outputs they produce, and the outputs you want them to produce? (e.g.  inputting 6 outputs 7 but I want to output 9)

Comment: Inputs should be basically two lists of numbers of the same length. No other constraint. The output should a single list with the formula applied to each member of the other two lists producing a single number per row, thus output should be the same length of the input lists.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you are trying to do. Is there a problem statement describing what you are supposed to do that you could add?

Comment: I am trying to compute gains and losses over a financial investiment over a period of 12 months. Gains and losses are defined with that formula over there. I am doing this in Excel, and I can't bring it into Python code....

Comment: I can see a few ways to organize it. My advice is to try computing each term `(x[i] - x[i - k])*n[i - k]`, considering each `i` to be a row and each `k` to be a column of a matrix. So you're filling in the lower triangle of the matrix. Then sum up the nonzero elements on each row. Try constructing the matrix first, printing it out and verifying it's right, and then calling a separate function to add up the row elements.

Comment: @RobertDodier you nailed it! it worked perfectly! i will add the solution to the answer. Thank you very much Robert.

Comment: Great, glad to hear you got it working.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION (Thank you @RobertDodier):

```
rows = [x for x in range(len(X))]
cols = [x for x in range(len(X))]
matrix = [[0 for i in range(len(X))] for j in range(len(X))]
for i in rows:
    for k in cols:
        term = (X[i] - X[i - k]) * Y[i - k]
        matrix[i][k] = term
        if k >= i:
             break
 main = []
 for e in matrix:
     o = sum(e)
     main.append(o)
```